# Can't create svg in d3.js

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I wrote a function that returns svg but faced an error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuECB.jpg)):

> Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined"

This is how I add the library :

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'

markerSvgIcon (options) {
      const svg = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'svg')
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      const triangle = d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle').size(195)
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      const svgTri = d3.select(svg)
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', triangle)
        .attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + 14 + ',' + 31 + ')' })
        .style('fill', '#35c377')
      console.log(svg)
      return svg
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) says, `d3.ns` has been renamed to `d3.namespaces`.

It should be:

```
const svg = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, 'svg')
```

Comment: @Mehdi It was almost simultaneously. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: const triangle = d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle').size(195) same problem here ".svg.symbol is not a function"

Comment: Make sure you refer to the latest API and not legacy D3 code. There's no `d3.svg`, https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md . It's likely `d3.symbol().type('triangle').size(195)`, https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.7/README.md#symbol